# How do I count up in python with a Url

Tags: python, counting

I'm not really sure how to explain what I am asking.

So what I have written is

```
    count = 1
    while count <= 100:
         print("https://api.roblox.com/Users/", count)
          count += 1
```

The goal is to print down https://api.roblox.com/Users/(count)

But what it ends up printing is ('https://api.roblox.com/Users/', (count))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a `https://api.roblox.com/Users/(count)` string. The way to do it is:

```
 "https://api.roblox.com/Users/" + str(count)
```

Your previous code creates a tuple containing a string and an int, which is what is printed:

```
>>> count = 15
>>> print("https://api.roblox.com/Users/", count)
('https://api.roblox.com/Users/', 15)
```

But if you concatenate the strings, it does what you want:

```
>>> count = 15
>>> print("https://api.roblox.com/Users/" + str(count))
"https://api.roblox.com/Users/15"
```

Comment: Also, note that OP's `print`s are tuples. That suggests that OP is running python 2. So you'll need to `from __future__ import print_function` before printint

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I might have gotten you wrong, but you can print tuples in Python3 the same way OP did: `print(1,2)` works perfectly.

Comment: `print(1,2)` works in py3, but does not print a tuple - it prints `1 2`. However, in py2, that would print `(1,2)`. See the difference?